# Should I split this Django model or not?

Tags: python, django, django-models, refactoring

I have two models in an app for rating the music tracks, I want to refactor the models.

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    """ Description: Author model """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class MusicTrack(models.Model):
    """ Description: Music Track Model """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    link = models.URLField()

    # rating data
    rating_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is the initial setup, I want to separate the ratings from the music app, but I am not sure whether to refactor the setup, should  I consider refactoring the rating data to another model? 
I consider not to refactor because, when I display music track information, I have to show ratings too, that is an extra join/query per song. I consier refactoring because I think its better to have rating to be separated, just like reviews.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    rating_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        ...?

class MusicTrack(models.Model):
    """ Description: Music Track Model """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    link = models.URLField()
    rating = models.OneToOneField(Rating)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Questions
1. Should I consider refactoring `MusicTrack` to a separate model, `Rating`?
2. What are the advantages of separation over not sperating?
3. If I refactor `MusicTrack` to a `Rating` model, what would be the `__unicode__` method to display the title of the related `MusicTrack`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overloading the meaning of rating.

If you want to store each individual rating for accounting purposes you could have a model for that, which you may want to do to ensure users can't rate twice (but then you need to add an identifier also)

If you just want to show the rating of a track, you could keep that on the model. It's fine.

I wouldn't overload unicode unless it's useful to display that record, but you could overload with "Rating: %d" or "Rating: %d for %s".

Answer (score 0):

Your Rating object is not a real object. It's more a behavior. Indeed, a music track can be rated but also an artist or an album. In python, there is no Interface to implement hebavior, but we have multiple inheritance. 
So here is what I recommend you :

1. Create an abstract RateModel :

```python
class RateModel(models.Model):
     rating_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)

     class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

2. Inherit your objects that needs this behavior from `RatedModel` class

```python
class MusicTrack(RateModel):
```

If most of your apps need a model, I recommend you to create a `core` app and place your model in it.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, Keep both solutions.

1. Keep avarage/count field in MusicTrack model in order to get instant access of total rates.
2. Keep separated rating in another model linked with ex. user.
   This one will allow user to track his history of rates and will avoid problem that user will rate many times one music track.

Comment: so that won't be same value on different tables? sounds better like a user model related field. I guess it will be much difficult to update both the fields at the same time, much expensive if it is same value over two tables.

Comment: Read about signals in django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save
In post_save there's 'created' argument. If created is True then someone has added a new rate. So add that to your Rating model and on post_save update MusicTrack statistic fields.